# How do I map a CHAR(1) to a boolean using Hibernate for Java?

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I map a CHAR(1) to a boolean using Hibernate for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `true_false` or `yes_no` types will do this for you.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! I saw where I could create a UserType, but I figured there was an easier way now, and this was it.

Comment: For example: <property name="deleted" type="yes_no" .../>

Comment: <property name="expired" column="EXPIRED" type="yes_no" />

When I do this I get this error , I have my variable as boolean and db type as char(1)

[9/30/09 15:25:41:258 PDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R  at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(ByteToCharUTF8.java:262)
[9/30/09 15:25:41:258 PDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.t.a(t.java:16) 

This is killing me..!!!

Answer (score 2):

CharBooleanType is probably what you are looking for http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/type/class-use/CharBooleanType.html

edit: dtsazza's answer is probably more useful if you just want to get going and use characters y/n or t/f. If those don't match your usage you can implement your own type using CharBooleanType.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I could use a UserType, but I thought there may be a simpler way, and dtsazza gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can map like this:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType")
@Column(name = "IsValid", columnDefinition = "CHAR(1)", length = 1)
private Boolean valid;
```